# Angular ng-options for bounded select elements

Tags: angularjs, html-select, ng-options

I'm almost there but stuck on one little detail. I can't seem to get the "name" property of the selected Car Make's "Car Model" to actually show up on the select menu. At the moment, it seems to be showing the correct number of options, but the options are visibly BLANK. Here's my code to help better explain...

```
$scope.carMakes = [
    {
        name: 'Honda',
        models: [{name:'Accord'}, {name: 'Civic'}, {name: 'CRX'}]
    },
    {
        name: 'Toyota',
        models: [{name:'Camry'}, {name: 'Forerunner'}]
    }
];

   <div class="input-group">
        <label>Vehicle Make</label>
        <select id="carMake" ng-model="carMake" ng-options="carMake as carMake.name for carMake in carMakes track by carMake.name">
            <option value="">All</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group carModels">
        <label>Vehicle Model</label>
        <select id="carModel" ng-model="carMake.model" ng-options="carMake.model as carMake.model.name for carMake in carMake.models">
            <option value="">All</option>
        </select>
   </div>
```

Can someone please tell me why even though the carModel select options show up, the "name" isn't being displayed? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want something like this:

```
<select id="carModel" ng-model="carMake.model" ng-options="carModel as carModel.name for carModel in carMake.models">
    <option value="">All</option>
</select>
```

We're using carModel.name as the display and setting the value as the object itself. So in your controller, `$scope.carMake.model` will be equal to the model object. So if the user selects "Accord" then in your controller:

```
$scope.carMake.model.name === 'Accord' // True
```

would evaluate to true after the selection is made.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, Nicholas, but I'm afraid I'm not following your proposed solution. I may be interpreting it incorrectly, but it looks like you're saying to set the model name manually? This is not what I'm looking to achieve.

I need it so that, if someone selects "Honda" from the list of carMakes, then the next select menu only shows the "Models" from that selected make (Honda).

Comment: I'm sorry - I guess my solution was unclear. You should change the ng-options attribute of your #carModel select element as is shown in my response. The second code snippet is to demonstrate the value of `$scope.carMake.model.name` in the controller if the user were to select "Accord" in the drop-down.

Comment: Ah, that makes perfect sense. Works like a charm. Thank you so much!